# MappingException(Attempt to add id) after upgrading to spring boot 2.2.X

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

After upgrading the spring boot to 2.2.4 (from 2.1.x), org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies to Hoxton.RELEASE and org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-dependencies to Horsham.RELEASE.

Getting the following exception when trying to create index document.

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Attempt to add id property private java.util.Map .CatalogIndex.document but already have property private java.lang.String .CatalogIndex.id registered as id. Check your mapping configuration!

Please find the entity class hierarchy.  I have removed all the getter and setter for simplicity.

---

```
package mypackage.entity;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Parent;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CatalogIndex {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Parent(type = "Initiative")
    private String initiativeId;

    private List<Map<String, Object>> typeHierarchy;

    private Map<String, Object> document;

    private List<Map<String, Object>> filters;
}
```

---

```
package mypackage.entity;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Document(indexName = "cataloginitiative")
public class CatalogInitiativeIndex extends CatalogIndex {   }
```

---

Comment: can you please share the code of your entity class?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Added the entity class in above post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Data Elasticsearch, when inspecting the Entity class, tries to figure out which property of the class is to be used as the **Id** property. A property qualifies for this if one of the following is true:

- the property is annotated with `@Id`
- the property is named *id*
- the property is named *document*

So in your case you have the property *id* which has a matching name and the annotation, and the property *document* with a matching name.

You have to rename your property *document* to somthing different.

Comment: Are any new validations added between elastic search for identifier.  This used to work earlier with spring boot 2.1.x.

Comment: strange, this logic has been in spring data elasticsearch for years

Comment: Thanks Meisch.  I was held up with other work and could not get time to work on this.

Not sure how this code was working fine with spring boot 2.1.11. 

As you suggested, I have renamed the document field to different name (like document1 for now) and it is working fine.  

Thanks,
Santhosh.

Comment: Recently upgraded to Spring Boot 2.2.X, as per @P.J.Meisch suggestion i have just renamed variable document to (myDocument) and not updated @Jsonproperty("document"). Mapping Exception got resolved. [Now i am facing different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62714962/spring-boot2-2-x-spring-elastic-search6-8-x-different-jsonproperty-and-f) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem like this:

```
@Table("table_name")
public class tableName{

    @Id
    private Long userId;
    @Id
    private Long roleId;

}
```

remove both @Id annotations

```
@Table("table_name")
public class tableName{

    private Long userId;       
    private Long roleId;

}
```