# Spring Boot(2.2.X) - Spring Elastic Search(6.8.X) - Different JSONProperty and Field Name

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, spring-data-elasticsearch

Updated Spring boot to **2.2.X** from **2.1.X** and elastic search to **6.8.X** from **6.3.X**.

[Got mapping exception, to resolve Mapping exception, renamed document variable to myDocument.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004445/mappingexceptionattempt-to-add-id-after-upgrading-to-spring-boot-2-2-x/60035030#60035030)

Now on `elasticSearchRepo.SaveAll(objectTosave)` value is not persisted in document.
Other properties like id, category are present in the document.

Is there any way to have different fieldName and jsonProperty?

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Document(indexName="my_document_index", type="information", createIndex=false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnKnown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyInstance
{
  @Field
  private String id;

  @Field
  private String category;

  @Field
  @JsonProperty("document")
  private MyObject mydocument;
  
  /** JSON Creator **/
  @JsonCreator
  public MyInstance(@JsonProperty("id") id, @JsonProperty("category") category,
         @JsonProperty("document") mydocument) 
  {
     this.id = id;
     this.category = category;
     this.mydocument = mydocument;
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not have an `@Id` field in your entity. What are you doing with the constructor parameters _id_ and _category_?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch my bad, I have posted error code block alone, now i have edited my post. I'm trying to avoid re-indexing elastic search and my concern is if i update Json property there might be impact on other functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need to annotate the `id` property with `@Field`, you should rather put `@Id` there. Although this is not needed, as the name of the property is enough, it makes it clearer what it is.

As for the `mydocument` property not being persisted: It is but in Elasticsearch with the name *mydocument*. The `@JsonProperty("document")` defines the name of this property in JSON when mapped by Jackson, when you get this in over a REST endpoint for example. Renaming to `mydocument` inhibits the error that the property is interpreted as id property.

But I think you want to have as *document* in Elasticsearch as well. You can define the name of a property in Elasticsearch by setting it in the `@Field` annotation:

```
@Document(indexName="my_document_index", createIndex=false)
public class MyInstance
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String category;

    @Field(name = "document")
    @JsonProperty("document")
    private MyObject mydocument;

}
```

Comment: I have tried adding name property in field, ended up with Mapping exception. Caused by: `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Attempt to add id property.` To resolve mapping exception i have renamed the variable name after upgrading spring boot and elastic search.